# how to auto re-run loopback server after change code or config file

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

someone told that `slc run` will work when change code, but my test is not. And no one said how to do when change config files, is it a way skip re-run server.js by handle?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [nodemon](http://nodemon.io/) to this:

```
nodemon -x 'slc run' -w common -w server
```

Comment: to be exact: `nodemon -x 'slc run' -w common -w server`